# When deploying a CorDapp, must the JAR be signed by default?

Tags: digital-signature, corda, signature

When deploying a Corda 4.0 CorDapp to UAT, must the Jar be signed?

We have tried using devMode = true - which causes the node to recognize the flows in the CorDapp, but when we set devMode to false it seems the node is unable to recognize the CorDapp.

Answer (score 2):

This could be because the JAR has been signed using the default development key. This is the case when `devMode` is set to `true` in your build.gradle.

If this is the case you need to add `cordappSignerKeyFingerprintBlacklist=[]` to the `node.conf`. If devMode=false, the Corda development key is blacklisted as it's completely insecure. This is suitable for PoC purposes only, NOT PRODUCTION.

*The correct fix is to sign the app with a your 'own' key.*

You can also switch off Jar signing when building the CorDapp by setting `cordapp { signing { enabled false } }` in the `build.gradle`, which should cause it not to be signed.

More information can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#signing-the-cordapp-jar